# My computer is stuck on login screen

Tags: login, login-screen

I setup Ubuntu 3.10 and now I am logged in, and it won't do anything! How do I start Ubuntu?

Comment: what shows on the screen?

Comment: Just a black screen with my username

Comment: Press enter and type your password.

Comment: I did, I'm trying that one guys answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate... I had the same problem, Type in `sudo apt-get update` then type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` then `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install unity` once all that is done type `startx` tell me if anything goes wrong from there

Comment: This worked but how do I run windows 8 without deleting Ubuntu?